# How does the execution context look like in simple example

Tags: javascript

thank you for helping me out.

In a class I am taking I have come across the following code:

```
var carlike = function(obj, loc){
    obj.loc = loc;
    obj.move = move;
    return obj;
};

var move = function(){
    this.loc++;
};

var ben = carlike({}, 9);
```

It is my understanding that when the function `carlike` is invoked on the last line during the creation phase of its execution context the variable `move` is set to `undefined`. So my question is: at which point is `move` set equal to `function() {this.loc++;};`? I find this confusing since the move function is defined after the carlike function. So how does `carlike` have access to the environment after it.

I really would like to know how this works under the hood in terms of the execution context, scope etc.

some things I have read to try and understand this:

http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/chapter-1-execution-contexts/
http://corporate.tuenti.com/en/dev/blog/functions-and-execution-contexts-in-javascript-2

Comment: The compiler pass and the execution are different things and could take different paths. The compiler in JS goes through the code from the top and validates variables and some other things... the variables are "logically" move to the top of their scope and set to be available to it, that's why move is available as variable to it's scope, but obj.move is a different variable declared for the object obj and assigned the value of the "global" move.

Answer (score 0):

It has access to that move variable because although the function move is declared after the function carlike, the function carlike does not reference move until after move has already been declared, since carlike is called after move is defined as a function.  If you make the call to carlike above the definition of move, then move will be set to undefined, since that function does not exist yet.

Comment: this however does not correspond with what I have read about lexical scope. Citing from a well known book on the topic: "No matter where a function is invoked from, or even how it is invoked, its lexical scope is only defined by where the function is declared".